# how to save elements as a variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array

```
a=[1,3,7,5,8,9,2,1]
```

and this matrix

```
       1st,2nd,3rd
matrix=[[1,3,10],
        [3,7,20],
        [5,8,12],
        [2,3,30],
        [3,3,14],
        [8,9,25],
        [5,3,30],
        [7,5,11],
        [8,9,21],
        [2,1,0],
        [9,2,15]]
```

I want to "save" or "store" the elements from array a in pairs as variable such as this form

(1st,2nd),(2nd,3rd),(3rd,4th), and so on till (7th,8th)

looking like this:

```
(1,3),(3,7),(7,5),(5,8),(8,9),(9,2),(2,1)
```

Trying to save these "pairs" as above format to identify the 3rd column from matrix using 1st and 2nd column info as pair:

```
       1st,2nd,3rd
matrix=[[1,3,**10**],
        [3,7,**20**],
        [5,8,**12**],
        [2,3,30],
        [3,3,14],
        [8,9,25],
        [5,3,30],
        [7,5,**11**],
        [8,9,**21**],
        [2,1,**0**],
        [9,2,**15**]]
```

To summarize, Not necessarily need to save the "pairs". I just want the 3rd column information driven from 1st and 2nd column from the matrix by pairs from the array a

lastly, I want to calculate the sum of the determined 3rd column elements from pairs info:

```
(1,3),(3,7),(7,5),(5,8),(8,9),(9,2),(2,1)

10+20+11+12+21+15+0=sum1
```

Any help?

Comment: What exactly, among all of these steps, is causing you a problem?

Comment: Try using a dictionary to store all the values rather than using a ton of variables.

Answer (score 0):

First let's create a dictionary to store the values corresponding to the pairs:

```py
pair2val = dict()
a=[1,3,7,5,8,9,2,1]
matrix=[[1,3,10],
        [3,7,20],
        [5,8,12],
        [2,3,30],
        [3,3,14],
        [8,9,25],
        [5,3,30],
        [7,5,11],
        [8,9,21],
        [2,1,0],
        [9,2,15]]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
   pair2val[(a[i],a[i+1])] = 0
```

Now let's look for the values in the `matrix` and calculate the sum of them:

```py
sum_ = 0
for list_ in matrix:
    cur_pair = (list_[0],list_[1])
    if cur_pair in pair2val:
       pair2val[cur_pair] += list_[2]
       sum_ += list_[2]
print(f"sum: {sum_}")
print(f"pairs: {pair2val}")
```

**Output:**

```py
sum: 114
pairs: {(1, 3): 10, (3, 7): 20, (7, 5): 11, (5, 8): 12, (8, 9): 46, (9, 2): 15, (2, 1): 0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions however i am getting this error message:                                  

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Comment: At which line you're getting the error, exactly? @nDev
I edited my answer, I think it'll work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension and tuple comprehension for this task:

```
matrix=[[1,3,10],
        [3,7,20],
        [5,8,12],
        [2,3,30],
        [3,3,14],
        [8,9,25],
        [5,3,30],
        [7,5,11],
        [8,9,21],
        [2,1,0],
        [9,2,15]]
column_1_and_2 = {i: j[:-1] for i, j in enumerate(matrix)}
column_3 = tuple(i[-1] for i in matrix)
summed_column_3 = sum(column_3)
```